# General equation of a conic.

Tags: conic-sections

I would like to know the derivation of the general equation of a conic:

$$Ax^{2} + Bxy + Cy^{2} + Dx + E y + F = 0$$

I have searched over the internet, but I did not find any resource which doesn't make use of trigonometry.

Comment: What is the equation supposed to govern? Ah nevermind, I missed the title.

Answer (score 4):

To help you get started:

A conic section is the intersection of a cone and a plane.

$$\cases{ax+by+cz +d = 0&\text{plane}\\x^2+y^2 = z^2&\text{cone}}$$

The cone equation comes from the circle equation $x^2+y^2 = R^2$ where we let the third coordinate $z$ steer the radius when increasing.

Then what may be needed is to rotate the result into a plane and maybe let something more be scalable so we get only two coordinates.

Comment: So ultimately it all comes down to Pythagoras.

Comment: Yes the circle (cone) is Pythagoras. That's where the second order terms come in.

Comment: That guy knew his stuff.

Comment: Yes Pythagoras was quite famous for many things. But maybe most for the right angle triangle formula.